# Problem in jqGrid sorting

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have a session data which I am binding to jqGrid.
I want to implement sorting on jqGrid.
For this I converted my session data like

```
DataTable dtProduct = (DataTable)Session["ProductSearchResult"];
dtProduct.DefaultView.Sort = sidx;
```

But sorting is not yet working. If I am missing any other step please tell me.

Comment: Show how you defined the settings of your jqGrid itself. You also need to set the sorting criteria on that one as well.

Comment: Do you use commercial version of jqGrid from http://www.trirand.net/ or you try to use `DataTable` with the Free, Open Source package from http://www.trirand.com/blog/ ?